# Platform to develop kiosks

Tags: python, xbmc

My team wants to setup a kiosk to show our success metrics and related information. A quick search on kiosks didnt return anything as such. Is there a platform which can be extended with plugins defined for this use case ?

Comment: yes it is called a TFT-Display   ...  you can use python + kivy to develop android apps if thats what your asking ...

Comment: Thanks Joran. I was looking for software platform.I'll look into python+kivy.